# Text To Speech - TOMSOFT

Tags: iphone, text-to-speech

I haven't been able to get a hold of the people over at tomsoft http://www.tomsoft.co.uk/ and I want to know if anyone has used their TTS Engine. I'm debating whether or not to buy it, and I want to know, does it call home? How is it integrated?

I'm also worried that since they are not replying to emails sent long ago, I may not receive the engine after my purchase?

Thanks Guys!

P.S. this is for the iPhone SDK.

Answer (score 0):

Afaik this company here is the right one for you. :)

[Nuance](http://www.nuance.com/realspeak/)

They provide realy good software, but in fact it will cost a lot more than 99usd, so I don't know if its suiteable for you.

Comment: I should have mentioned this was for an iPhone App.